# Hide long copyright message at top of all files

Tags: emacs, hide, copyright-display

We have 15 line long copyright messages at the top of all our source-code files.

When I have them open in emacs, that wastes a lot of valuable space.
Is there any way to get emacs to always a hide a certain message but still leave it in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function that narrows your buffer to everything but the first 15 lines.

```
(defun hide-copyright-note ()
  "Narrows the current buffer so that the first 15 lines are
hidden."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line 15)
    (narrow-to-region (point) (point-max))))
```

Then all you need to do is make sure that this function is called for every file that contains a copyright note. This can be done by adding a hook, preferably to the major mode of your file. For instance you could add the above function definition and the following line to your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'hide-copyright-note)
```

This would call the function 'hide-copyright-note whenever you open a C file.

In practice, you would probably want to make your hook-function more clever, either by checking if a copyright note to hide actually exists or by running hide-copyright-note only if a file is in a certain directory etc.

For instance, to stick with the C example, you could insert the following test into the above function:

```
(defun hide-copyright-note ()
  "Narrows the current buffer so that the first 15 lines are
hidden."
  (interactive)
  (when (copyright-message-p)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (forward-line 15)
      (narrow-to-region (point) (point-max)))))

(defun copyright-message-p ()
  "Returns t when the current buffer starts with a Copyright
note inside a C-style comment"
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (looking-at "\\s */\\*\\(:?\\s \\|\\*\\)*Copyright\\b")))
```

As for your other concern:

> *When I have them open in emacs, that wastes a lot of valuable space.*

...or you could just scroll down. To achieve this automatically, we could use the following function instead of `hide-copyright-note`:

```
(defun scroll-on-copyright ()
  "Scrolls down to the 16th line when the current buffer starts
with a copyright note."
  (interactive)
  (when (copyright-message-p)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (beginning-of-line 16)
    (recenter 0)))
```

However, the reason I recommended the first variation is that if you merely scroll down automatically, then whenever you jump to the beginning of the buffer (`M-<`) you'll have to scroll down again manually. This problem does not occur with the narrowing solution.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Thomas, the function works great! Do you have any suggestions about how to make this only apply to when the file starts with a copyright notice? For example I'd be glad to have it apply to anything starting with `"/*\n * Copyright"`. As for your other comment, is there any way to have emacs automatically scroll forward 15 lines on open? That might be a better solution for simplicity. Thanks again.

Comment: @sligocki: The test whether a file actually contains a copyright notice can easily be achieved using regular expression search. I've edited my answer to work for `"/*\n * Copyright"` as per your request - however, are you sure that that won't make the notice 16 lines long? In any case, instead of using a fixed number of lines, you could just search for the end of the initial comment (`"*/"`) and jump to the first non-empty line after that. Doing that would make the approach more flexible for Copyright notices of different lengths.

Comment: Note that this solution conflicts with line numbers (they aren't offset correctly).

Comment: @ideasman42 Have a look at this workaround: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24833/preserve-original-line-numbering-for-a-narrowed-region

Answer (score 9):

You can use [hideshow minor mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html) which is a standard built-in package that has a generalized command called `hs-hide-initial-comment-block` that will do what you want without having to know how long the top comment section is. You can add it to the mode-hook of any language, but here's an example using C:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'hs-minor-mode t)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'hs-hide-initial-comment-block t)
```

Note, it does not hide specifically *just* the copyrights, but the full initial comment block which may hide useful documentation, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [folding-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode). Basically, all you need is a way to identify the parts to be folded, and then use `folding-top-mark` and `folding-bottom-mark` to mark them.  There are hacks to do that with EMACS elisp code by the way, so you should be easily able to find code that can be adapted.

Comment: Use [hideshow minor mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14017141/462302) which is a built-in package instead of folding-mode.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs comes with `elide-head`, specifically for that, since Emacs-21.
In Emacs-29 we rename it to `elide-head-mode`.

Comment: It's not working for me in ruby-mode, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @EvDolzhenko: You don't provide enough info even for my crystal ball.

Comment: sorry, but can you explain how one is supposed to use it? "Not working" in my case meant that I'm editing Ruby file (stock Emacs 30.0.50), then I do `M-x elide-head-mode` it says "mode enabled" and then nothing happens, header in the file with copyright info stays on the screen.

Comment: @EvDolzhenko: Did you read the docstring?  Does your header match something in `elide-head-headers-to-hide`?